# How to populate Excel ComboBox with data from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to populate a combobox in Excel file with data from SQL Server.

Here is code for event:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Generation").Activate

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

On Error Resume Next

With cn
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
                        "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
                        "Server=" & "192.160.160.150;" & _
                        "Database=" & "em_Consumer;" & _
                        "User Id= " & "User" & _
                        "Password = " & "server123"
    .Open
End With

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

sqltextexec = " SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE  schema_id = 7 AND name LIKE 'FinalCalculated%' ORDER BY create_date "

rs.Open sqltextexec, cn

rs.MoveFirst

With Sheets("Generation").ComboBox1
    .Clear
    Do
        .AddItem rs![Name]
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF

End With

End Sub
```

This code works on my computer and on my colleague's as well (we are from DB team) but analysts who don't work with DB don't get list populated in the file.

Is it possible the program uses Windows authentication to connect to the DB?

Comment: Do they have access to the database server on your network? That connection string is using server authentication (username=User, password=server123), not windows authentication.

Comment: Yes they have access. This user was created specially for analysts and it was the idea to make this file to connect to DB using these credentials. But I don't know why it works on my computer and doesn't work on their.

Comment: Have you run a line-by-line debugger of the program on their computer? Are you getting an error in the connection anywhere? Or is the returned recordset just blank for some unknown reason?

Comment: No, I didn't try to run debugger on their computer

Comment: If it is possible, I would suggest that as the first step. Find out if the SQL connection is even being made, and if not, what error response are you getting? If they are on a different subnet (e.g., 192.160.161.150), then the networking switch device they are on will need to translate traffic to allow the two networks to speak with eachother. Otherwise, you'll need to either (1) allow external access to the SQL server through the firewall and let the users connect via public IP, or (2) they'll have to use a VPN.

Comment: Add a `MsgBox rs.RecordCount` after you retrieve the recordset on their computer to see if it is populated

Comment: Also, try to connect from *their* machine and open SSMS ( SQL server management studio ) and see if the connection has been made

Comment: They will be able to connect. 
I have a button which runs select from the same DB and returns table in the excel. And it works.
The code for it:

Sub Button8_Click()
  
ActiveSheet.Range("C21:H25").Clear
   
   Dim qt As QueryTable
    
    
   sqlstring1 = "SELECT  * FROM CreateDailyReport2 "
                      
   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=getConnectionStr2, Destination:=Range("C21"), Sql:=sqlstring1)   

    .Refresh
 
    End With
             
End Sub

Comment: And function is :

Private Function getConnectionStr2()
'DRIVER={SQL Server};
getConnectionStr2 = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};" & _
                   "DATABASE=em_Consumer;" & _
                   "SERVER=192.160.160.150;" & _
                   "UID=User;" & _
                   "PWD=server123;"
End Function

Comment: The first step would still be to attempt the program from their computer. Remember to remove the `On Error Resume Next` beforehand. Also, this may be unrelated, but workbook_open events must be in the workbook module. Therefore any reference to the `ActiveWorkbook` should instead be done using `ThisWorkbook`. But like I said, this may not be the cause of your problem.

Comment: A bit problematic to try it from their computers...
What does this code do? "On Error Resume Next"
On my computer it works both with this string and without it

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` makes it so that when an error occurs, it is ignored, and the process continues from the next line down.

Comment: after removing this line they get an login error. "run time error 2147217843 (80040e4d)"
Can it be that syntax of credentials is incorrect?

Comment: I don't know guys what is wrong with code as my level of VBA is quit poor but I bet it tries to use windows authentication. Analyst sent me a screenshot with error and it says "Login failed for user Name.Surname" so i believe it means that program tries to use win authentication.

Answer (score 0):

### Connection String Error

It seems there is an error in your connection string. The user ID needs to have a semi-colon after it. 
Change this

```
With cn
 .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
                        "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
                        "Server=" & "192.160.160.150;" & _
                        "Database=" & "em_Consumer;" & _
                        "User Id= " & "User" & _
                        "Password = " & "server123"
```

To this

```
With cn
 .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
                        "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
                        "Server=" & "192.160.160.150;" & _
                        "Database=" & "em_Consumer;" & _
                        "User Id= " & "User;" & _
                        "Password = " & "server123"
```

That was an elusive little bugger.

---

### Edit

I'm having trouble pinpointing the issue here, so perhaps a working example will better assist you at this point...

```
Function getSqlData(queryString As String, myUsername As String, myPassword As String, database As String) As Recordset

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim serverName As String


serverName = "192.160.160.150"


With conn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
        "Data Source=" & serverName & ";" & _
        "Initial Catalog=" & database & ";User Id=" & myUsername & ";" & _
        "Password=" & myPassword & ";Trusted_Connection=no"
        .Open
End With


Set rst = conn.Execute(queryString)

Set getSqlData= rst

End Function
```

This will return your recordset.

Comment: Additionally, SSPI security integration can use either windows authentication *or* server authentication (although there is apparently some debate about this). I'm guessing it was performing win auth on your machine.

Comment: So maybe I can change SSPI to smth else to use only server authentication?

Comment: @Almazini I think SSPI is recommended, but yes, you can change `Integrated Security` to equal `false` and that will force it to use the provided username and password. However, SSPI is supposed to use the username and password *if* it is provided. So fixing the syntax error should work.

Comment: I tried to change parameter's value to False and now I also get an error: run time error 214721887 (8004e21). 

after syntax issue fixing nothing changed :(

Comment: I tried but still doesn't work. Please take a look to my answer below. Maybe function is not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

today I tried to write it from scratch using @lopsided help. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("generation").Activate
            
Dim rstt As Recordset

MsgBox "1"
                    
Set rstt = getData()
                         
End Sub

-------------------------------------------------

Private Function getData()

Dim conn As New Connection
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim sqlstring As String
Dim rwcnt As Integer


MsgBox "2"

sqlstring = "SELECT productname FROM dbo.products WHERE recalc = 1"
     
With conn

 .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
                     "Data Source=192.160.160.150;" & _
                     "Initial Catalog=em_Consumer;" & _
                     "User Id=User;" & _
                     "Password=server!;" & _
                      "Trusted_Connection=no"

.Open

End With

MsgBox "3"

Set rst = conn.Execute(sqlstring)

rwcnt = rst.RecordCount

MsgBox rwcnt

MsgBox "5"

Set getData = rst

MsgBox "6"

End Function
```

So when i open the file I get messages:

1 which means that program started;

2 which means that it entered the function;

3 which means that there is no issues with connection;

**!! then I get -1 value as record count which means that something is wrong**

I tried to run this query in management studio and it returns 50 rows

Then program goes further and I get 5 and 6 ...

Do you have any ideas what is wrong with the code?

## ---------------------------------------------

Maybe it can help, code which works fine but returns table not recordset in the same document:

```
Sub Button3_Click()

    ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
               
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    
    sqlstring1 = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Report"
     
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=getConnectionStr2, Destination:=Range("A3"), Sql:=sqlstring1)

    .Refresh
    
    End With
           
End Sub

----------------------------------

Private Function getConnectionStr2()
'DRIVER={SQL Server};
getConnectionStr2 = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};" & _
                   "DATABASE=em_Consumer;" & _
                   "SERVER=192.160.160.150;" & _
                   "UID=user;" & _
                   "PWD=server!;"
End Function
```

Comment: That runtime error you were getting yesterday was for an invalid password. Did you fix that issue?

Comment: @Lopsided most probably it was because of missing semicolon! Now there is no such error. Now I am stuck on getting list into recordset

Comment: We can continue this conversation in chat for real-time support. [Click here to join.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48493/vba-discussion)

Comment: that is great idea! maybe googletalk? my acc is  almazini (at) gmail

Comment: @Lopsided hi! Lets make a chat today

Comment: I apologize Almazini, but I have business this morning. I'm going to have to let you figure this out on your own :(